# connection in a different thread can't read tables created in another thread?

Tags: sqlalchemy, pytest, python-unittest, cherrypy

In a testing suite I have a fixture that drop all the tables in an engine, then start fresh and create all the tables. After this fixture logic, my test case runs, using the newly created table.
The fixture and the test case are run in the MainThread, while the database consumer is a web application server run in another thread.
However, I keep getting: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: ***
I've checked that they are using the same in-memory engine, but different connections(this is correct). And I've checked that the fixture does run before the consumer thread starts running.
What could be possible cause?

My code is as below:

```
import os
import pytest
import cherrypy


class DAL:
    def __init__(self,
                 path="database",
                 filename=None,
                 conn_string=None,
                 echo=False):
        if filename is None and conn_string is None:
            conn_string = "sqlite:///:memory:"
        elif conn_string is not None:
            conn_string = conn_string
        else:
            conn_string = f'sqlite:///{os.path.abspath(path)}/{filename}'
        self.conn_string = conn_string
        engine = create_engine(conn_string, echo=echo)
        Session_Factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self.Session = sqlalchemy.orm.scoped_session(Session_Factory)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"<DAL>object: {self.conn_string}, at {hex(id(self))}"

    def get_a_dbsession(self):
        opened_db = self.Session()
        return opened_db

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.get_a_dbsession()

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, exception_traceback):
        opened_db = self.Session()
            try:
                opened_db.commit()
            except:
                opened_db.rollback()
                raise
            finally:
                self.Session.remove()

        else:
            opened_db.close()
            raise exception_type

    def create_schema(self):
        SchemaBase.metadata.create_all(self.Session().connection().engine)


class SAEnginePlugin(cherrypy.process.plugins.SimplePlugin):
    def __init__(self, bus, dal):
        """
        The plugin is registered to the CherryPy engine.
        """
        cherrypy.process.plugins.SimplePlugin.__init__(self, bus)
        self.dal = dal

    def start(self):
        self.bus.subscribe("bind-session", self.bind)

    def stop(self):
        self.bus.unsubscribe("bind-session", self.bind)
        if self.dal:
            del self.dal

    def bind(self):
        """
        Whenever this plugin receives the 'bind-session' message, it applies
        this method and bind the received session to the engine.
        """
        # self.dal.Session.configure(bind=self.dal.engine)
        session = self.dal.get_a_dbsession()
        return session


class SATool(cherrypy.Tool):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        This tool binds a session to the engine each time
        a requests starts and commits/rollbacks whenever
        the request terminates.
        """
        cherrypy.Tool.__init__(self,
                               'on_start_resource',
                               self.bind_session,
                               priority=20)

    def _setup(self):
        cherrypy.Tool._setup(self)
        cherrypy.request.hooks.attach('on_end_resource',
                                      self.close_session,
                                      priority=80)

    def bind_session(self):
        """
        Attaches a session to the request's scope by requesting
        the SA plugin to bind a session to the SA engine.
        """
        session = cherrypy.engine.publish('bind-session').pop()
        cherrypy.request.db = session

    def close_session(self):
        """
            Commits the current transaction or rollbacks if an error occurs.
            In all cases, the current session is unbound and therefore
            not usable any longer.
        """
        if not hasattr(cherrypy.request, 'db'):
            return

        try:
            cherrypy.request.db.commit()
        except:
            cherrypy.request.db.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            cherrypy.request.db.close()
            cherrypy.request.db = None


# Register the SQLAlchemy tool
cherrypy.tools.db = SATool()


class UnitServer:
       ...

    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_in()
    def list_filtered_entries(self):
        ...
        queryOBJ = cherrypy.request.db.query(classmodel_obj)
        ...

############# main module code below ############:

# mocking 'db':
dal = database.DAL()

# configure cherrypy:
SAEnginePlugin(cherrypy.engine, dal).subscribe()


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True) # automatically run before every test case
def mocked_dal(request):
    # first, clean the database by dropping all tables:
    database.SchemaBase.metadata.drop_all(dal.Session().connection().engine)
    # second, create the schema from blank:
    dal.create_schema()
    # third, insert some dummy data record:
    ...
    db.commit()
   

class TestMyUnitServer(cherrypy.test.helper.CPWebCase):
    @staticmethod
    def setup_server():
        ...
        server_app = UnitServer()
        cherrypy.tree.mount(server_app, '', {'/': {'tools.db.on': True}})

    def test_list_filtered_entries_allentries(self):
        ...
        self.getPage('/list_filtered_entries',
                     headers=[("Accept", "application/json"),
                              ('Content-type', 'application/json'),
                              ('Content-Length',
                               str(len(json.dumps(query_params)))),
                              ("Connection", "keep-alive"),
                              ("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")],
                     body=serialized_query_params,
                     method="POST")
        self.assertStatus('200 OK')
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#threading-pooling-behavior

Comment: @llja I'm aware of this documentation. I'm not using a single connection across different thread. I'm using the recipe to generate a thread local connection for each request. But the problem is that the new connection cannot "see" the tables created by the old thread.

Comment: The relevant part is "so that all access to the engine within the current thread use the same `:memory:` database - **other threads would access a _different_ `:memory:` database.**"

Comment: @Llja My goodness, how could I miss that! Is there a way around?

Comment: I don't know why it is designed this way, but I think from a practical point of view, this initiation of another completely different `:memory:` database is not necessary. How to switch it off?

Comment: If I want to set up a fixture filled with dummy tables and rows, there is no way to pass this `:momory:` database onto the test case?

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I'm not too well versed in using SQLite in a multi-thread environment, other than knowing this bit of information. In theory you could use a static pool combined with the required configuration to disable the same thread check, but I would imagine that to not work too well with threads trying to run concurrent transactions using the same connection.